# Причина постановки запятой в предложении

Tags: запятые

*"Мне нужна ваша поддержка, давайте пообщаемся"*
По какому правилу мы ставим запятую перед "давайте"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь два простых предложения, они разделяются запятой. Если важно подчеркнуть причинно-следственные связи, можно поставить и тире.

Comment: Интересный момент: но тире тогда будет интонационным, здесь нет прямого следствия, есть лишь предложение.

Comment: Можно добавить *поэтому.*

Comment: И что? Это не то. Нет фактического действия. Следствие — это вытекающее действие, а не то, что можно сказать по какой-то причине (нужда поддержки). Сравнить: *Мне нужна ваша поддержка — предлагаю пообщаться. Мне нужна ваша поддержка — мы начинаем общаться.* И то это притянуто за уши в плане стилистики. В примерах правил по обе стороны глаголы. Тогда оно звучит. Проблема "по какому правилу?" часто простой не является. А в вопросе спрашивается о нём.